# What is this kind of video artifact called (grafitti)

Tags: video

This lyrics video contains multiple examples, ie. 0:41 to 0:43 and 1:00 to 1:02 and 1:31 to 1:38. 
I mean the grafitti zipping quickly through. I've seen this effect earlier, but I don't know what it's called.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is neither an artifact nor graffiti. That is a (simulation of) writing directly onto a [film leader](https://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-5992598-writing-scratches-on-old-film-leader-loop).